# iOS - Pass Data Multiple Times From Parent View Into Container View's View

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller, uicontainerview

I have a `UIPageViewController`, and one of its `View Controller`s has a `Container View` where its parent `View Controller` passes data into it so the container can display dynamic data. I currently have the parent view passing data into the view within the container view with this `prepareForSegue` method:

```
//In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"CALLED PREPARE FOR SEGUE");
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"viewEmbed"]) {
        //pass data
    }
}
```

However, this `prepareForSegue` method is only called once (note my NSLog debugging statement), but I need to pass different data to the child view every time the `UIPageViewController` swipes to the parent view. I also noticed that the `viewDidLoad` method fires only once in my parent view because the `UIPageViewController` retains the state of its pages.

Is there a way to re-instantiate (call viewDidLoad again) the parent view every time it is swiped to from the `UIPageViewController`? I'm thinking that would make the `prepareForSegue` method fire more than once, which I need it to do. Or am I thinking about this the wrong way and there is a more elegant solution?

Any help or advice would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The view did load is only called once as is the segue since your view will only be loaded once. You should do this manually by

- register for delegate updades on the `UIPageViewController`
- impelemt

  `- (void)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController * nonnull)pageViewController
  willTransitionToViewControllers:(NSArray<UIViewController *> * nonnull)pendingViewControllers` to receive these updates
- call a method on you child **but not** the `viewDidLoad`,`viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear` since there is code that should not executed multiple times. You should copy you current viewDidLoad code from you child into a new method and call this method from the parent when the delegate method is called

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning this, but my `UIPageViewController` already passes data to the parent view while it's swiping toward the parent view. I tried setting the child view's class variables from within the parent view controller by doing [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier] but this doesn't work. Basically, I don't understand how to access the view controller inside the container view without doing `prepareForSegue`.

Comment: By setting the child view controller's class variables I mean setting the property variables declared in the .h file.

Comment: instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier will create a new instance of that viewController - this will not change the existing one. You just have to store a reference to the parent (or child) in your prepareForSegue method

Comment: Oooooooh I never thought of that. I'll try that right now, thanks!